# PXE based installation always sets hostname as 'kickseed'

Tags: server, dhcp, hostname, kickstart

I am using PXE based provisioning of Ubuntu 12.04.5. I have PXE, TFTP, DHCP server in place. All my configurations specified in kickstart file are set correctly except the hostname. The machine always gets hostname as 'kickseed'.

Following is the entry in my kickstart file:

`network --bootproto dhcp --device eth0 --hostname myhost`

I found following related issue which has been fixed in Ubuntu 12.04.4:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kickseed/+bug/879605

However this one was for static whereas I face issue during dhcp.

Any idea how I could resolve this issue or any pointers where I can look into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due the reverse lookup failure. After resolving this the issue was resolved.